# Get the latest image from external storage in android

Tags: android, camera, gallery

I want to load the latest image from the external storage in Android.

```
Do you have any ideas how to get the name of the latest image?
```

Currently, I load a certain picture from the gallery this way:

```
    File externalDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File directory = new File (externalDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
    File file = new File(directory, "pic.jpg"); 

    FileInputStream streamIn = null;
    try {
        streamIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So is there a way to load the `latest`?

Comment: do you want user to select image or directly load image

Comment: I want to load the image. I just need to know the name of the latest image

Comment: do you have path ?

Comment: As above shown, I can load the picture, in this case pic.jpg, if I know the name of the image

Comment: I just need to know the name of the `latest` picture

Comment: What do you consider to be 'the latest image' ? Prettey unclear.

Comment: The last taken image?!

Comment: Well you should tell. Taken by who? Created by which app? Copied by which app? Downloaded by downloadmanager? There are so many possibilities.

Comment: `I load a certain picture from the gallery this way:`. That is not from 'the gallery' but from External Storage root directory.

Comment: And do you know how to load the `most recent` taken by my camera app from the External Storage root directory?

Comment: You did not tell where your camera app is saving the pictures. Is it your app? Or the standard app provided with the device? Why so unclear?

Comment: `how to load the most recent taken`. In the same way of course. When you know the name the rest is the same. I think your question is not to the point.

Comment: And now tell me how do I get the name of latest?

Comment: You have not answered my questions concerning this. Why not?

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, //the album it in
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN, 
    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE
    };
final Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver()
        .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, 
               null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

// Put it in the image view
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pictureView);
    String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
    File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
    if (imageFile.exists()) {   // TODO: is there a better way to do this?
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);         
    }
}
```

Use [content resolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html)

**Updated** :

if you mean you want to load an image from a certain directory you create for storing image you need to make sure in every device that certain directory is created. You can use a while loop to loop through all the image by checking wether the `BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME` also known as album have the same name to your created album. If yes get the first picture since you already order it by descending order sort by date time.

```
 int albumColumn = cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME);

do{
    String album = cur.getString(albumColumn);
    if(album == "YOUR CREATE DIR"){
        break;
    }
}while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Integrate this code with the above code with your own logic. Basically the BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME is the album which I mention earlier.

Comment: So what is `getContext`? Inside my activity I can't access that

Comment: use your context to replace it. getApplicationContext() if you in activity, getActivity() if you in fragment. You can use this or Youractivity.this as well if you in activity.

Comment: Ok works to load from the gallery, but my images are always stored in the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` so how can I access that path? Or how can I save my photos the gallery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983654/android-how-to-add-an-image-to-an-album on how to store image to gallery.

Comment: If you really want to get it based on latest inserted your best way is to store it into gallery otherwise you could make your image's name save with current date time and get all the image's name and reordering it with your own code which is quite too much work to do. So why not just save it to gallery right?

Comment: `So why not just save it to gallery right`. One cannot save images to 'the gallery' as the Gallery app is no storage place or file system but only an app that can show pictures that are on your device.

Comment: @greenapps that true but since he already save it in external directory rather than internal it will still appear at the album.

Comment: @teckwei I can save it now to the gallery/Pictures.. But  your code doesn't recognize the photos in the Pictures folders so do you have any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: `cursor.moveToFirst()` always false?

Answer (score -1):

you may try this

```
String path = "/mnt/sdcard/Videos/Videoname"; // Your path

String fileName = new File(path).getName(); // you file name
```